# KSZ8081 PHY address configuration

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, addressing, phy

I'm using this [KSZ8081](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/ksz8081mnx-rnb.pdf) PHY transceiver.

I'm unable to understand how to configure the PHYAD[0:2] pin and the B-CAST_OFF pin.

As far as I read, the PHY Broadcast address will always be "0" and the unique address of the PHY can never be "0".

So, when I pull down the pins of PHYAD[0:2], won't the address of the PHY become 0?

I'm stuck to understand these pins and the concept of broadcast address with respect to PHY. Can someone please check and clarify this.

Comment: So don't set the PHY addresses to 0 then if that is the easiest way. But you did not read the datasheet. You can disable broadcast address and you can select some other address to be broadcast address.

Comment: How to set the broadcast address to a different one?

Comment: That information is in page 12 of the datasheet, it explains both methods how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is, yes, pulling address config pins low will result the PHY address being 0.

Datasheet says it is configurable to any value between 0 and 7.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what about the B-CAST_OFF pin? What does that pin mean and how to configure that?

Comment: The strapping options and what they do are explained on page 12.

Comment: Oh, so pulling up the B-CAST_OFF pin, we can make the Broadcast address as per our wish . But pulling down the B-CAST_OFF pin will make the PHY broadcast address as 0, right?